# How can I remove feature selection from my layeroverlay in mapguide API?

Tags: layers, features, api, overlay, mapguide

I can add feature to my layeroverlay on mapguide API, but I don't know how to remove it. 
Can you help me find a method to remove a feature from a selection ?

This is how i add features to my layer :

```
MgFeatureReader featureReader = layer.SelectFeatures(queryOptions);
MgSelection mgSelection = new MgSelection(map);
mgSelection.AddFeatures(layer, featureReader, 0);
mgSelection.Save(resourceService, strMapName);
map.Save();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found my answer:

```
MgSelection mgSelection = new MgSelection(map);
mgSelection.Save(resourceService, strMapName);
```